# Maximize does not expand content to the top of the window [Windows MAUI]

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, maui, maui-windows, maximize-window

I am trying to get a totally maximized Window with .NET Maui 8.0.0preview4, but an empty bar remains where the title-bar used to be.

[image: Red - Page, Black - Titlebar]

For the example, I've ammended the Maui template by making the "Click me" button toggle the window's maximized state, with the following code inspired by [Verslui's article on the topic](https://blog.verslu.is/maui/full-screen-disable-minimize-maximize-for-net-maui-windows-apps/):

```cs
        private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var window = Window.Handler.PlatformView as MauiWinUIWindow;
            var handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
            var id = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(handle);
            var appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(id);

            switch (appWindow.Presenter)
            {
                case Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter overlappedPresenter:
                    if (overlappedPresenter.State == Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenterState.Maximized)
                    {
                        overlappedPresenter.SetBorderAndTitleBar(true, true);
                        overlappedPresenter.Restore();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        overlappedPresenter.SetBorderAndTitleBar(false, false);
                        overlappedPresenter.Maximize();
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
```

I also scrapped out Shell and use the MainPage directly. Is seems like `SetBorderAndTitleBar` isn't actually removing the titlebar, just the buttons.

Any ideas for how I can get a true full-screen experience would be much appreciated. Here is the [repro repo](https://github.com/aidanjbailey/MaximizeMaui) for those interested. Thanks!

Comment: I can reproduce while same code works fine in "pure" WinUI3. Seems like a MAUI limittion, shortcoming or simply a bug. You should post in MAUI github.

Comment: I've made an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15676). Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

First, add `using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;` in the MauiProgram.cs.

Second, add the code below in the MauiProgram.cs.

```
#if WINDOWS
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
            // Make sure to add "using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;" in the top of the file 
            events.AddWindows(windowsLifecycleBuilder =>
            {
                windowsLifecycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                    window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = false;
                    var handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                    var id = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(handle);
                    var appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(id);
                    switch (appWindow.Presenter)
                    {
                        case Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter overlappedPresenter:
                            break;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
#endif
```

Then the button will work well.

Comment: This does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: @AidanBailey - Actually that works for me. I tried `ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = false` in the onclick event handling but it didn't work there. Seems to be working in the Create event see also https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2190. PS: the rest after  `window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = false` is useless

Comment: Yes this seems a fix for .NET 7, but remains broken for .NET 8 preview. At least it has no effect when added to my repro. Unless it is working for you in .NET 8? For then I am even more confused. Thanks for both of your help.

Comment: @AidanBailey - I've only tested .NET 7. Maybe it's not too late for Microsoft to fix it for .NET 8 (and maybe document it somehow...)